# Satellite’s Position and Path on 2D Map

Tags: orbital-motion, astronomy, geometry, satellites

When the ISS orbit the Earth, its path traced on a 2D Mercator Earth Map is similar to a sinusoidal wave. I am wondering is there any way to determine the trig function of the wave, knowing the orbital height (which decides its speed) and direction in relation to Earth's rotational axis. This will possibility allow you to determine the position of a satellite at an specific time on a 2D map.

Comment: It has been done for you - [Live Map of Satellite Positions](https://in-the-sky.org/satmap_worldmap.php).

Comment: Thanks @Farcher is there anyway to recreate this program while showing the trig function of the path?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this belongs on spaceexploration.se